# method _or in Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression giving 'AND' Instead of 'OR' when i called sql() method

Tags: php, cakephp, conditional-statements, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to add OR SQL Query Statement to my CakePHP project, but notice I am getting AND instead of OR.

I am getting this string when I use SQL(), and no OR is include whereas OR is expected

```
SELECT Blacklist.id AS `Blacklist__id`, 
       Blacklist.provider AS `Blacklist__provider`, 
       Blacklist.receiver AS `Blacklist__receiver`, 
       Blacklist.platform AS `Blacklist__platform`, 
       Blacklist.brokers AS `Blacklist__brokers` 
FROM blacklist Blacklist 
WHERE (brokers = :c0 AND provider = :c1 AND platform=FXCMMetaTrader4)
```

I tried the code below, to but instead of OR I am getting AND.

Why is this working this way and how can I avoid this?

```
//fill blacklist data
  $blacklistQuery  = $blacklistModel->find()
            ->select(['id', 'provider', 'receiver', 'platform', 'brokers'])
            ->order(array('created' => 'desc'))
            ->where(function (QueryExp $exp, Query $q) use ($accountBroker, $accountLogin,$platform) {
                $orBrokerCond = $exp->or_(['brokers' => $accountBroker]);
                $orProviderCond = $exp->or_(['provider' => $accountLogin]);
                $orPlatformCond = $exp->or_('platform='. $platform);

                return $exp->add($orBrokerCond)
                    ->add($orProviderCond)
                    ->add($orPlatformCond);
            });

        // ->where("provider = $accountLogin");

echo $blacklistQuery->sql();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner expression objects usually do not affect outer expression objects, ie the main expression doesn't really care about what type of expression you are passing to it.

What you are doing there is creating 3 separate expression objects, each containing only a single condition. Each of those objects will compile itself to a single conditional statement, and those statements will then be concatenated using `AND` as you are passing them to the main expression that uses `AND` by default.

What you are trying to create could simply be expressed as:

```
return $exp->or_([
    'brokers' => $accountBroker,
    'provider' => $accountLogin,
    'platform' => $platform,
]);
```

If you where to add `OR` conditions to another expression, then you'd pass such an object with multiple conditions, ie:

```
$or = $exp->or_([
    'brokers' => $accountBroker,
    'provider' => $accountLogin,
    'platform' => $platform,
]);

return $exp->add($or);
```

ps, do *NOT* do stuff like `'platform='. $platform`, that's a possible SQL injection vulnerability!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**